# Creating Primary Keys or Unique Keys

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a table called playlists.

A user can't create a playlist with the same name more than once and the same song can't be added to a playlist more than once.

I tried to create a composite key and it didn't work.

Can someone please guide how to accomplish this task?

When I did the way it is in the code, I am getting errors for duplicate entries.

I am able to insert the initial entry, however, I get errors for duplicate entries even if the SongCode is different.

```sql
    CREATE TABLE Playlists (
      SongCode varchar(400) NOT NULL,
      PlaylistName varchar(400)  NOT NULL,
      UserCode varchar(400) NOT NULL,
      Entry_At datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
    );
    ALTER TABLE Playlists
      ADD Primary KEY (UserCode,PlaylistName),
      ADD UNIQUE KEY SongCode_PlaylistName (SongCode,PlaylistName);
```

Sample Data

```
INSERT INTO Playlists (SongCode, PlaylistName, UserCode) VALUES
        ('0bc4bb05-e8fa-11e9-a21e-86ae283e70f9', 'Test1', '20cbd799-de71-11e9-8269-86ae283e70f7')
INSERT INTO Playlists (SongCode, PlaylistName, UserCode) VALUES
    ('0bc4bb05-e8fa-11e9-a21e-86ae283e70f10', 'Test1', '20cbd799-de71-11e9-8269-86ae283e70f7')
```

Comment: There's a limit on the size of indexes, and `400 + 400` is too big.

Comment: Do you really need usernames 400 characters long?

Comment: You need separate tables for `Songs` and `Users`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Songs & Users already have separate tables. I am trying to create a Playlist table

Comment: What version of SQL are you using? Your ``CREATE TABLE`` statement gives me ``#1709 - Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes`` on MySQL 5.7.7

Comment: @kmoser 8.0.16 mySQL workbench

Comment: Your ``PRIMARY`` key requires ``UserCode`` and ``PlaylistName`` to be unique for each record. However, your second ``INSERT`` attempts to insert a record with the same ``UserCode`` (``20cbd799-de71-11e9-8269-86ae283e70f7``) and ``PlaylistName`` (``Test1``) as the first record. Did you expect that to succeed?

Comment: @JS . . . I don't see any foreign key references.

Comment: @kmoser I am using the PK as a pair so shouldn't my second insert work?

Comment: @JS Your PK consists of the ``UserCode`` and ``PlaylistName``. The second ``INSERT`` uses the same values for ``UserCode`` and ``PlaylistName`` as the first ``INSERT``, which violates the constraint of your PK (which requires each record have a unique ``UserCode``/``PlaylistName`` combination).

Comment: @kmoser I also tried using unique instead of PK which didn't work either. Any suggestions on how to resolve?

Comment: @JS According to your requirements, "A user can't create a playlist with the same name more than once". And yet your second ``INSERT`` attempts to do just that. It looks like either you don't know what you want to do, or you aren't being clear about what you want to do.

Comment: @kmoser with my second insert, I am trying to insert different song to the same playlist by same user. The second insert has different song code.

Comment: @JS The second insert may have a different ``SongCode``, but it has the same ``PlaylistName`` as the first insert. The ``PRIMARY KEY (UserCode,PlaylistName)`` is preventing the second record from being inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Try below statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Playlists (
  SongCode varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  PlaylistName varchar(400)  NOT NULL,
  UserCode varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  Primary KEY(UserCode,PlaylistName),
  CONSTRAINT SongCode_PlaylistName UNIQUE(SongCode,PlaylistName),
  Entry_At datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
);
ALTER TABLE Playlists
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE Playlists (
      id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      SongCode varchar(400) NOT NULL,
      PlaylistName varchar(400)  NOT NULL,
      UserCode varchar(400) NOT NULL,
      Entry_At datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
    ALTER TABLE Playlists
```

Check this if correct : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=db70a568504cf0b2a27119c4e2f55d77
:D